# CEO Pay Ratio Data

Tags: data-request, usa

The recently released [Rewarding or Hoarding report](https://ellison.house.gov/sites/ellison.house.gov/files/Rewarding%20Or%20Hoarding%20Full%20Report.pdf) indicates...

> According to the SEC, approximately 3,571 companies are required to file ratio disclosures

Then this report goes into details on...

> the first 225 Fortune 500 companies to publicly disclose this information.

[image: Companies with Top 25 CEO to median worker pay ratios]

Where can I find the CEO to median worker pay ratio data from the current disclosures of these 3,571 companies? The analysis of 255 of the Fortune 500 disclosures is interesting; but seeing an analysis of the other companies would offer further insights.

If a compiled dataset doesn’t exist, then what is the best path to collect the data that has been released? Is there perhaps an SEC API to utilize?

I’m curious to see how many median pay jobs could potentially be formed if there were regulations restricting the pay ratio. If such an analysis has already been done with this data that would be even better.

> For historical context, in 1965, the average CEO made 20 times the average worker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ellison report says that

> These data were compiled by Bloomberg from the SEC’s EDGAR database.

Unfortunately, it seems that SEC's EDGAR [doesn't](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/quickedgar.htm) provide API.

One can extract some information from [the page](https://www.bloomberg.com/graphics/ceo-pay-ratio/) on the Bloomberg site. The JS code is obfuscated, paste the following into browser console, emulating user actions:

```
length = document.querySelector('#dvz-asset-asset-company-datalist').children.length

button = document.querySelector('.next')
company = button.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild;
ratio = button.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.children[2].children[2].firstChild

results = {}

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
  results[company.innerText] = parseInt(ratio.innerText.replace('\xA0', ''));
  button.click();
  }

console.log(results)
```

This is how output looks like (~760 records as of May 21, 2018):

```
"3M Co.": 324
"ACADIA Pharmaceuticals Inc.": 54
"AES Corp.": 190
"AGCO Corp.": 297
"AGNC Investment Corp.": 76
"AMC Networks Inc.": 449
"AMETEK Inc.": 144
"ANSYS Inc.": 77
"AO Smith Corp.": 428
"ARRIS International Plc": 65
"AT&T Inc.": 366
"AbbVie Inc.": 144
"Abbott Laboratories": 251
"Acadia Healthcare Company Inc.": 334
"Activision Blizzard Inc.": 306
"Advance Auto Parts Inc.": 329
"Advanced Micro Devices Inc.": 121
"Aetna Inc.": 235
"Affiliated Managers Group Inc.": 88
"Aflac Inc.": 300
"Agios Pharmaceuticals Inc.": 24
"Air Lease Corp.": 45
"Akamai Technologies Inc.": 84
"Akorn Inc.": 86
"Alaska Air Group Inc.": 116
"Albemarle Corp.": 114
"Alcoa Corp.": 121
"Alexandria Real Estate Equities Inc.": 86
"Alexion Pharmaceuticals Inc.": 93
"Align Technology Inc.": 920
"Alkermes Plc": 70
"Alleghany Corp.": 129
"Allegion Plc": 177
"Allergan Plc": 349
"Alliance Data Systems Corp.": 145
"Alliant Energy Corp.": 54
"Allison Transmission Holdings Inc.": 98
"Ally Financial Inc.": 84
"Alnylam Pharmaceuticals Inc.": 7
"Alphabet Inc.": 0
"Altria Group Inc.": 114
"Amazon.com Inc.": 59
"Ameren Corp.": 66
"American Airlines Group Inc.": 195
"American Campus Communities Inc.": 226
"American Electric Power Company Inc.": 102
"American Express Co.": 327
"American Financial Group Inc.": 151
"American Homes 4 Rent": 6
"American International Group Inc.": 697
"American National Insurance Co.": 52
"American Tower Corp.": 260
"American Water Works Company Inc.": 53
"Ameriprise Financial Inc.": 223
"Amgen Inc.": 127
"Amphenol Corp.": 670
"Anadarko Petroleum Corp.": 106
Andeavor: 131
"Antero Resources Corp.": 114
"Anthem Inc.": 262
"Aon Plc": 217
"Apache Corp.": 99
"Apartment Investment & Management Co.": 111
"Apple Hospitality REIT Inc.": 26
"AptarGroup Inc.": 162
"Aptiv Plc": 2526
"Aqua America Inc.": 44
"Arch Capital Group Ltd.": 104
"Archer-Daniels-Midland Co.": 276
"Arconic Inc.": 96
"Arista Networks Inc.": 50
"Armstrong World Industries Inc.": 50
"Arrow Electronics Inc.": 206
"Arthur J Gallagher & Co.": 126
"Aspen Insurance Holdings Ltd.": 39
"Associated Banc-Corp.": 81
"Assurant Inc.": 222
"Assured Guaranty Ltd.": 58
"Athenahealth Inc.": 108
"Athene Holding Ltd.": 49
"AutoNation Inc.": 268
"Autodesk Inc.": 107
"AvalonBay Communities Inc.": 131
"Avangrid Inc.": 21
"Avery Dennison Corp.": 746
"Axalta Coating Systems Ltd.": 139
"Axis Capital Holdings Ltd.": 48
"BB&T Corp.": 150
"BGC Partners Inc.": 168
"BOK Financial Corp.": 43
"BWX Technologies Inc.": 50
"Baker Hughes a GE Co.": 208
"Ball Corp.": 157
"Bank of America Corp.": 250
"Bank of Hawaii Corp.": 82
"BankUnited Inc.": 59
"Baxter International Inc.": 355
"Bemis Company Inc.": 158
"Berkshire Hathaway Inc.": 2
"Best Buy Company Inc.": 699
"Bio-Rad Laboratories Inc.": 87
"BioMarin Pharmaceutical Inc.": 114
"Biogen Inc.": 92
"Black Knight Inc.": 80
"BlackRock Inc.": 195
"Blue Buffalo Pet Products Inc.": 286
"Booking Holdings Inc.": 599
"BorgWarner Inc.": 247
"Boston Properties Inc.": 96
"Boston Scientific Corp.": 205
"Brandywine Realty Trust": 57
"Bright Horizons Family Solutions Inc.": 80
"Bristol-Myers Squibb Co.": 169
"Brixmor Property Group Inc.": 57
"Brookdale Senior Living Inc.": 73
"Brown & Brown Inc.": 73
"Bruker Corp.": 67
"Brunswick Corp.": 152
"Bunge Ltd.": 386
"Burlington Stores Inc.": 763
"CBRE Group Inc.": 150
"CBS Corp.": 595
"CDW Corp.": 82
"CF Industries Holdings Inc.": 87
"CH Robinson Worldwide Inc.": 130
"CIT Group Inc.": 88
"CME Group Inc.": 90
"CMS Energy Corp.": 41
"CNA Financial Corp.": 102
"CNX Resources Corp.": 82
"CSX Corp.": 27
"CVS Health Corp.": 320
"Cable One Inc.": 55
"Cabot Oil & Gas Corp.": 163
"Cadence Design Systems Inc.": 72
"Camden Property Trust": 78
"Capital One Financial Corp.": 261
"CarMax Inc.": 214
"Carlisle Cos Inc.": 148
"Carter’s Inc.": 876
"Caterpillar Inc.": 213
"Cavium Inc.": 49
"Cboe Global Markets Inc.": 70
"Celanese Corp.": 157
"Celgene Corp.": 62
"Centene Corp.": 379
"CenterPoint Energy Inc.": 83
"CenturyLink Inc.": 212
"Cerner Corp.": 54
"Charles River Laboratories International Inc.": 299
"Charter Communications Inc.": 148
"Cheniere Energy Inc.": 60
"Chesapeake Energy Corp.": 125
"Chevron Corp.": 180
"Chimera Investment Corp.": 17
"Chipotle Mexican Grill Inc.": 814
"Choice Hotels International Inc.": 71
"Chubb Ltd.": 301
"Church & Dwight Company Inc.": 98
"Cigna Corp.": 279
"Cimarex Energy Co.": 93
"Cincinnati Financial Corp.": 54
"Cinemark Holdings Inc.": 752
"Citigroup Inc.": 369
"Citizens Financial Group Inc.": 155
"Citrix Systems Inc.": 87
"Clean Harbors Inc.": 47
"CoStar Group Inc.": 147
"Cognex Corp.": 46
"Cognizant Technology Solutions Corp.": 390
"Colfax Corp.": 90
"Colgate-Palmolive Co.": 641
"Colony NorthStar Inc.": 16
"Columbia Property Trust Inc.": 47
"Comcast Corp.": 458
"Comerica Inc.": 152
"CommScope Holding Company Inc.": 832
"Commerce Bancshares Inc.": 90
"Concho Resources Inc.": 86
"Conduent Inc.": 358
ConocoPhillips: 138
"Consolidated Edison Inc.": 96
"Continental Resources Inc.": 105
"CoreCivic Inc.": 62
"CoreLogic Inc.": 79
"CoreSite Realty Corp.": 51
"Corning Inc.": 356
"Corporate Office Properties Trust": 29
"Crane Co.": 91
"Credit Acceptance Corp.": 18
"Crown Castle International Corp.": 87
"Crown Holdings Inc.": 316
CubeSmart: 141
Cullen: 80
"Cummins Inc.": 275
"Cypress Semiconductor Corp.": 143
"CyrusOne Inc.": 67
"DCT Industrial Trust Inc.": 34
"DDR Corp.": 98
"DENTSPLY SIRONA Inc.": 151
"DISH Network Corp.": 33
"DST Systems Inc.": 96
"DTE Energy Co.": 91
"DaVita Inc.": 254
"Danaher Corp.": 218
"Delta Air Lines Inc.": 142
"Devon Energy Corp.": 100
"DexCom Inc.": 86
"Diamondback Energy Inc.": 76
"Dick’s Sporting Goods Inc.": 1015
"Digital Realty Trust Inc.": 76
"Discover Financial Services": 213
"Discovery Inc.": 522
"Dollar General Corp.": 658
"Dollar Tree Inc.": 747
"Dominion Energy Inc.": 109
"Domino’s Pizza Inc.": 461
"Domtar Corp.": 107
"Douglas Emmett Inc.": 221
"Dover Corp.": 237
"DowDuPont Inc.": 175
"Dr Pepper Snapple Group Inc.": 209
"Duke Energy Corp.": 175
"Duke Realty Corp.": 57
"Dunkin’ Brands Group Inc.": 48
"E*TRADE Financial Corp.": 62
"EBay Inc.": 143
"EOG Resources Inc.": 72
"EPR Properties": 26
"EQT Corp.": 81
"East West Bancorp Inc.": 87
"Eastman Chemical Co.": 167
"Eaton Corp Plc": 214
"EchoStar Corp.": 19
"Ecolab Inc.": 238
"Edison International": 62
"Edwards Lifesciences Corp.": 215
"Eli Lilly & Co.": 118
"Empire State Realty Trust Inc.": 157
"Endo International Plc": 171
"Energen Corp.": 54
"Entergy Corp.": 106
"Envision Healthcare Corp.": 140
"Equifax Inc.": 65
"Equinix Inc.": 107
"Equity Commonwealth": 22
"Equity LifeStyle Properties Inc.": 122
"Equity Residential": 151
"Erie Indemnity Co.": 51
"Essex Property Trust Inc.": 77
"Euronet Worldwide Inc.": 134
"Everest Re Group Ltd.": 48
"Eversource Energy": 127
"Exelixis Inc.": 34
"Exelon Corp.": 127
"Expedia Group Inc.": 431
"Expeditors International of Washington Inc.": 154
"Express Scripts Holding Co.": 303
"Extended Stay America Inc.": 98
"Extra Space Storage Inc.": 122
"Exxon Mobil Corp.": 108
"FLIR Systems Inc.": 142
"FMC Corp.": 258
"FNB Corp.": 125
"Facebook Inc.": 37
"Fastenal Co.": 58
"Federal Realty Investment Trust": 89
"Federated Investors Inc.": 58
"Fidelity National Information Services Inc.": 654
"Fifth Third Bancorp": 145
"FireEye Inc.": 46
"First American Financial Corp.": 159
"First Data Corp.": 2028
"First Republic Bank": 66
"First Solar Inc.": 92
"FirstEnergy Corp.": 90
"Fiserv Inc.": 151
"FleetCor Technologies Inc.": 1517
"Flowers Foods Inc.": 105
"Flowserve Corp.": 122
"Fluor Corp.": 152
"Foot Locker Inc.": 748
"Ford Motor Co.": 285
"Forest City Realty Trust Inc.": 91
"Fortinet Inc.": 35
"Fortive Corp.": 212
"Fortune Brands Home & Security Inc.": 136
"Freeport-McMoRan Inc.": 277
"GGP Inc.": 140
"GameStop Corp.": 211
"Gaming and Leisure Properties Inc.": 413
"Garmin Ltd.": 76
"Gartner Inc.": 94
"General Dynamics Corp.": 218
"General Electric Co.": 157
"General Motors Co.": 295
"Genesee & Wyoming Inc.": 101
"Genpact Ltd.": 127
"Gentex Corp.": 20
"Genuine Parts Co.": 139
"Gilead Sciences Inc.": 94
"Global Payments Inc.": 159
"GoDaddy Inc.": 31
"Graham Holdings Co.": 38
"Graphic Packaging Holding Co.": 109
"Great Plains Energy Inc.": 34
"Gulfport Energy Corp.": 52
"HCA Healthcare Inc.": 312
"HCP Inc.": 40
"HD Supply Holdings Inc.": 133
"Halliburton Co.": 290
"Hanesbrands Inc.": 1830
"Harley-Davidson Inc.": 143
"Hasbro Inc.": 160
"Hawaiian Electric Industries Inc.": 47
"Healthcare Trust of America Inc.": 123
"Henry Schein Inc.": 101
"Herbalife Ltd.": 193
"Hess Corp.": 90
"Hexcel Corp.": 118
"Highwoods Properties Inc.": 69
"Hilton Grand Vacations Inc.": 165
"Hilton Worldwide Holdings Inc.": 567
"HollyFrontier Corp.": 75
"Honeywell International Inc.": 333
"Host Hotels & Resorts Inc.": 35
"Hubbell Inc.": 234
"Hudson Pacific Properties Inc.": 64
"Humana Inc.": 344
"Huntington Bancshares Inc.": 145
"Huntington Ingalls Industries Inc.": 60
"Huntsman Corp.": 232
"Hyatt Hotels Corp.": 298
IAC: 256
"IDEX Corp.": 138
"IDEXX Laboratories Inc.": 121
"IPG Photonics Corp.": 68
"IQVIA Holdings Inc.": 388
"ITT Inc.": 198
"Illinois Tool Works Inc.": 420
"Illumina Inc.": 86
"Incyte Corp.": 64
"Ingersoll-Rand Plc": 335
"Ingredion Inc.": 320
"Intel Corp.": 211
"Interactive Brokers Group Inc.": 7
"Intercept Pharmaceuticals Inc.": 28
"Intercontinental Exchange Inc.": 106
"International Business Machines Corp.": 341
"International Flavors & Fragrances Inc.": 127
"International Paper Co.": 230
"Intrexon Corp.": 32
"Intuitive Surgical Inc.": 32
"Invesco Ltd.": 141
"Ionis Pharmaceuticals Inc.": 47
"Iron Mountain Inc.": 288
"JB Hunt Transport Services Inc.": 15
"JPMorgan Chase & Co.": 364
"JetBlue Airways Corp.": 65
"Johnson & Johnson": 452
"Jones Lang LaSalle Inc.": 192
"Juniper Networks Inc.": 74
"KAR Auction Services Inc.": 165
"Kansas City Southern": 128
"Kellogg Co.": 183
"KeyCorp.": 118
"Kilroy Realty Corp.": 86
"Kimberly-Clark Corp.": 332
"Kimco Realty Corp.": 56
"Kinder Morgan Inc.": 4
"Kirby Corp.": 52
"Kohl’s Corp.": 1264
"Kosmos Energy Ltd.": 23
"L Brands Inc.": 449
"L3 Technologies Inc.": 250
"LKQ Corp.": 135
"LPL Financial Holdings Inc.": 95
"Laboratory Corp of America Holdings": 280
"Lamar Advertising Co.": 80
"Landstar System Inc.": 101
"Laredo Petroleum Inc.": 51
"Las Vegas Sands Corp.": 747
"Lazard Ltd.": 67
"Lear Corp.": 1452
"Leggett & Platt Inc.": 428
"Leidos Holdings Inc.": 93
"Lennox International Inc.": 181
"Leucadia National Corp.": 489
"Liberty Broadband Corp.": 0
"Liberty Expedia Holdings Inc.": 0
"Liberty Interactive Corp QVC Group": 1810
"Liberty Property Trust": 50
"Life Storage Inc.": 89
"LifePoint Health Inc.": 262
"Lincoln Electric Holdings Inc.": 156
"Lincoln National Corp.": 219
"Live Nation Entertainment Inc.": 2893
"Lockheed Martin Corp.": 186
"Loews Corp.": 84
"LogMeIn Inc.": 92
"Lowe’s Cos Inc.": 469
"LyondellBasell Industries NV": 158
"M&T Bank Corp.": 72
"MDU Resources Group Inc.": 48
"MEDNAX Inc.": 81
"MFA Financial Inc.": 22
"MGM Resorts International": 396
"Macquarie Infrastructure Corp.": 103
"Macy’s Inc.": 806
"Mallinckrodt Plc": 102
"Manhattan Associates Inc.": 39
"ManpowerGroup Inc.": 2483
"Marathon Oil Corp.": 77
"Marathon Petroleum Corp.": 935
"Markel Corp.": 57
"MarketAxess Holdings Inc.": 51
"Marriott International Inc.": 395
"Marsh & McLennan Cos Inc.": 277
"Martin Marietta Materials Inc.": 131
"Marvell Technology Group Ltd.": 44
"Masco Corp.": 298
"Mastercard Inc.": 155
"Match Group Inc.": 47
"Mattel Inc.": 4987
"McDonald’s Corp.": 3101
"Medical Properties Trust Inc.": 31
"Merck & Company Inc.": 215
"Mercury General Corp.": 23
"MetLife Inc.": 200
"Mettler-Toledo International Inc.": 178
"Mid-America Apartment Communities Inc.": 134
"Mohawk Industries Inc.": 123
"Molson Coors Brewing Co.": 119
"Mondelez International Inc.": 403
"Monster Beverage Corp.": 256
"Moody’s Corp.": 187
"Morgan Stanley": 192
"Morningstar Inc.": 71
"Motorola Solutions Inc.": 148
"Murphy Oil Corp.": 113
"Murphy USA Inc.": 343
"Mylan NV": 317
"NCR Corp.": 213
"NRG Energy Inc.": 80
"NVIDIA Corp.": 88
"NVR Inc.": 51
"Nabors Industries Ltd.": 268
"Nasdaq Inc.": 132
"National Instruments Corp.": 163
"National Oilwell Varco Inc.": 239
"National Retail Properties Inc.": 53
"Navient Corp.": 147
"Nektar Therapeutics": 91
"Netflix Inc.": 133
"Neurocrine Biosciences Inc.": 30
"New York Community Bancorp Inc.": 112
"NewMarket Corp.": 24
"Newell Brands Inc.": 477
"Newfield Exploration Co.": 92
"Newmont Mining Corp.": 114
"NextEra Energy Inc.": 155
"NiSource Inc.": 51
"Nielsen Holdings Plc": 475
"Noble Energy Inc.": 88
"Nordstrom Inc.": 187
"Norfolk Southern Corp.": 130
"Northern Trust Corp.": 169
"Northrop Grumman Corp.": 185
"Norwegian Cruise Line Holdings Ltd.": 514
"Nu Skin Enterprises Inc.": 925
"Nucor Corp.": 133
"OGE Energy Corp.": 45
"ON Semiconductor Corp.": 972
"ONEOK Inc.": 53
"OPKO Health Inc.": 25
"Occidental Petroleum Corp.": 110
"Oceaneering International Inc.": 33
"Old Dominion Freight Line Inc.": 106
"Old Republic International Corp.": 37
"Olin Corp.": 92
"Omega Healthcare Investors Inc.": 47
"Omnicom Group Inc.": 596
"OneMain Holdings Inc.": 9
"Orbital ATK Inc.": 58
"Outfront Media Inc.": 86
"Owens Corning": 166
"Owens-Illinois Inc.": 197
"O’Reilly Automotive Inc.": 141
"PBF Energy Inc.": 60
"PG&E Corp.": 61
"PPG Industries Inc.": 382
"PPL Corp.": 130
"PVH Corp.": 1042
"PacWest Bancorp": 67
"Packaging Corp of America": 155
"Pandora Media Inc.": 75
"Paramount Group Inc.": 108
"Park Hotels & Resorts Inc.": 567
"Parsley Energy Inc.": 37
"Patterson-UTI Energy Inc.": 170
"PayPal Holdings Inc.": 274
"Penske Automotive Group Inc.": 168
"Pentair Plc": 264
"People’s United Financial Inc.": 84
"PepsiCompany Inc.": 650
"PerkinElmer Inc.": 200
"Perrigo Co Plc": 127
"Pfizer Inc.": 313
"Philip Morris International Inc.": 990
"Phillips 66": 138
"Piedmont Office Realty Trust Inc.": 47
"Pilgrim’s Pride Corp.": 114
"Pinnacle Financial Partners Inc.": 54
"Pinnacle Foods Inc.": 111
"Pinnacle West Capital Corp.": 82
"Pioneer Natural Resources Co.": 92
"Pitney Bowes Inc.": 142
"Platform Specialty Products Corp.": 117
"Polaris Industries Inc.": 199
"Pool Corp.": 86
"Popular Inc.": 83
"Praxair Inc.": 475
"Principal Financial Group Inc.": 119
"ProAssurance Corp.": 39
"Prologis Inc.": 204
"Prosperity Bancshares Inc.": 70
"Prudential Financial Inc.": 268
"Public Service Enterprise Group Inc.": 80
"Public Storage": 439
"PulteGroup Inc.": 69
"QEP Resources Inc.": 53
"Quanta Services Inc.": 116
"Quest Diagnostics Inc.": 215
"RPC Inc.": 31
"RSP Permian Inc.": 62
"Range Resources Corp.": 70
"Rayonier Inc.": 38
"Raytheon Co.": 172
"Realogy Holdings Corp.": 105
"Realty Income Corp.": 88
"Regal Beloit Corp.": 622
"Regency Centers Corp.": 59
"Regeneron Pharmaceuticals Inc.": 215
"Regions Financial Corp.": 202
"Reinsurance Group of America Inc.": 66
"Reliance Steel & Aluminum Co.": 199
"RenaissanceRe Holdings Ltd.": 37
"Republic Services Inc.": 187
"Retail Properties of America Inc.": 49
"Robert Half International Inc.": 507
"Rollins Inc.": 52
"Roper Technologies Inc.": 354
"Ross Stores Inc.": 1314
"Royal Caribbean Cruises Ltd.": 728
"Ryder System Inc.": 138
"S&P Global Inc.": 434
"SBA Communications Corp.": 130
"SCANA Corp.": 46
"SEI Investments Co.": 24
"SL Green Realty Corp.": 303
"SLM Corp.": 81
"SM Energy Co.": 44
"SS&C Technologies Holdings Inc.": 120
"STORE Capital Corp.": 51
"SVB Financial Group": 46
"Sabre Corp.": 100
"Salesforce.com Inc.": 30
"Santander Consumer USA Holdings Inc.": 49
"Schlumberger Ltd.": 234
"Seaboard Corp.": 175
"Sealed Air Corp.": 179
"Seattle Genetics Inc.": 53
"Sempra Energy": 134
"Service Corp International": 377
"ServiceMaster Global Holdings Inc.": 123
"ServiceNow Inc.": 250
"Signet Jewelers Ltd.": 594
"Silgan Holdings Inc.": 71
"Simon Property Group Inc.": 88
"Sirius XM Holdings Inc.": 84
"Six Flags Entertainment Corp.": 1804
"Skechers U.S.A. Inc.": 1512
"Snap-on Inc.": 208
"Sonoco Products Co.": 182
"Southern Copper Corp.": 40
"Southwest Airlines Co.": 93
"Southwestern Energy Co.": 80
"Spirit AeroSystems Holdings Inc.": 141
"Spirit Airlines Inc.": 62
"Spirit Realty Capital Inc.": 114
"Splunk Inc.": 36
"Sprouts Farmers Market Inc.": 233
"Square Inc.": 0
"Stanley Black & Decker Inc.": 357
"State Street Corp.": 236
"Steel Dynamics Inc.": 94
"Stericycle Inc.": 67
"Stryker Corp.": 209
"Sun Communities Inc.": 528
"SunTrust Banks Inc.": 159
"Synchrony Financial": 298
"Synovus Financial Corp.": 100
"T Rowe Price Group Inc.": 121
"T-Mobile US Inc.": 424
"TCF Financial Corp.": 55
"TEGNA Inc.": 87
"TESARO Inc.": 18
"Tableau Software Inc.": 18
"Tanger Factory Outlet Centers Inc.": 480
"Targa Resources Corp.": 52
"Target Corp.": 408
"Taubman Centers Inc.": 35
"Teledyne Technologies Inc.": 131
"Teleflex Inc.": 319
"Telephone & Data Systems Inc.": 96
"Tempur Sealy International Inc.": 440
"Teradata Corp.": 137
"Teradyne Inc.": 76
"Terex Corp.": 213
"Tesla Inc.": 1
"Texas Instruments Inc.": 210
"Textron Inc.": 165
"The Allstate Corp.": 230
"The Bank of New York Mellon Corp.": 354
"The Boeing Co.": 166
"The Charles Schwab Corp.": 146
"The Chemours Co.": 101
"The Coca-Cola Co.": 230
"The Dun & Bradstreet Corp.": 70
"The Gap Inc.": 2900
"The Goldman Sachs Group Inc.": 163
"The Goodyear Tire & Rubber Co.": 206
"The Hanover Insurance Group Inc.": 42
"The Hartford Financial Services Group Inc.": 143
"The Hershey Co.": 376
"The Home Depot Inc.": 552
"The Howard Hughes Corp.": 118
"The Interpublic Group of Cos Inc.": 264
"The Kraft Heinz Co.": 91
"The Kroger Co.": 547
"The Macerich Co.": 170
"The Michaels Cos Inc.": 497
"The Middleby Corp.": 26
"The Mosaic Co.": 94
"The PNC Financial Services Group Inc.": 201
"The Progressive Corp.": 136
"The Sherwin-Williams Co.": 323
"The Southern Co.": 114
"The TJX Cos Inc.": 1501
"The Timken Co.": 181
"The Travelers Cos Inc.": 154
"The Ultimate Software Group Inc.": 344
"The Wendy’s Co.": 295
"The Western Union Co.": 292
"The Williams Cos Inc.": 85
"Thermo Fisher Scientific Inc.": 324
"Tiffany & Co.": 783
"Time Warner Inc.": 651
"Torchmark Corp.": 104
"Total System Services Inc.": 114
"Tractor Supply Co.": 278
TransUnion: 74
"Transocean Ltd.": 81
"TreeHouse Foods Inc.": 165
"Tribune Media Co.": 139
"Trimble Inc.": 128
"Trinity Industries Inc.": 253
"TripAdvisor Inc.": 481
"Tupperware Brands Corp.": 357
"Twitter Inc.": 0
"Tyler Technologies Inc.": 45
"UDR Inc.": 129
"US Bancorp": 205
"US Foods Holding Corp.": 113
"USG Corp.": 72
"Ulta Beauty Inc.": 275
"Under Armour Inc.": 378
"Union Pacific Corp.": 166
"United Continental Holdings Inc.": 115
"United Parcel Service Inc.": 274
"United Rentals Inc.": 166
"United States Cellular Corp.": 131
"United States Steel Corp.": 77
"United Technologies Corp.": 235
"United Therapeutics Corp.": 203
"UnitedHealth Group Inc.": 298
"Uniti Group Inc.": 72
"Univar Inc.": 250
"Universal Display Corp.": 42
"Universal Health Services Inc.": 541
"Unum Group": 155
"Urban Outfitters Inc.": 5
"VEREIT Inc.": 89
"VF Corp.": 1353
"Valero Energy Corp.": 117
"Validus Holdings Ltd.": 20
"Valmont Industries Inc.": 91
"Vectren Corp.": 82
"Veeva Systems Inc.": 930
"Ventas Inc.": 285
"VeriSign Inc.": 52
"Verisk Analytics Inc.": 99
"Verizon Communications Inc.": 142
"Vertex Pharmaceuticals Inc.": 81
"Visteon Corp.": 454
"Vornado Realty Trust": 169
"Voya Financial Inc.": 115
"Vulcan Materials Co.": 94
"WABCO Holdings Inc.": 175
"WEC Energy Group Inc.": 113
"WESCO International Inc.": 113
"WEX Inc.": 173
"WP Carey Inc.": 45
"WPX Energy Inc.": 73
"WR Berkley Corp.": 119
"WR Grace & Co.": 74
"WW Grainger Inc.": 113
"Wabtec Corp.": 93
"Walmart Inc.": 1188
"Waste Management Inc.": 136
"Waters Corp.": 100
"Watsco Inc.": 163
"Wayfair Inc.": 2
"Weatherford International Plc": 220
"Webster Financial Corp.": 75
"Weingarten Realty Investors": 64
"Welbilt Inc.": 91
"WellCare Health Plans Inc.": 145
"Wells Fargo & Co.": 291
"Welltower Inc.": 116
"West Pharmaceutical Services Inc.": 111
"Westar Energy Inc.": 29
"Western Alliance Bancorp": 69
"Westlake Chemical Corp.": 103
"Weyerhaeuser Co.": 151
"Whirlpool Corp.": 356
"White Mountains Insurance Group Ltd.": 75
"Whiting Petroleum Corp.": 53
"Williams-Sonoma Inc.": 1477
"Willis Towers Watson Plc": 65
"Workday Inc.": 51
"World Fuel Services Corp.": 99
"Worldpay Inc.": 131
"Wyndham Worldwide Corp.": 398
"Wynn Resorts Ltd.": 777
"XL Group Ltd.": 84
"XPO Logistics Inc.": 38
"Xcel Energy Inc.": 120
"Xerox Corp.": 111
"Xylem Inc.": 151
"Yum China Holdings Inc.": 2818
"Yum! Brands Inc.": 1358
"Zebra Technologies Corp.": 110
"Zillow Group Inc.": 65
"Zimmer Biomet Holdings Inc.": 88
"Zions Bancorporation": 53
"Zoetis Inc.": 150
"Zynga Inc.": 12
```

Data for the Technology sector companies:

```
"ANSYS Inc.": 77
"ARRIS International Plc": 65
"Activision Blizzard Inc.": 306
"Advanced Micro Devices Inc.": 121
"Akamai Technologies Inc.": 84
"Alliance Data Systems Corp.": 145
"Alphabet Inc.": 0
"Amphenol Corp.": 670
"Arista Networks Inc.": 50
"Arrow Electronics Inc.": 206
"Autodesk Inc.": 107
"Black Knight Inc.": 80
"CDW Corp.": 82
"Cadence Design Systems Inc.": 72
"Cavium Inc.": 49
"Citrix Systems Inc.": 87
"Cognex Corp.": 46
"Cognizant Technology Solutions Corp.": 390
"CommScope Holding Company Inc.": 832
"Conduent Inc.": 358
"CoreLogic Inc.": 79
"Corning Inc.": 356
"Cypress Semiconductor Corp.": 143
"DST Systems Inc.": 96
"EBay Inc.": 143
"EchoStar Corp.": 19
"Euronet Worldwide Inc.": 134
"FLIR Systems Inc.": 142
"Facebook Inc.": 37
"Fidelity National Information Services Inc.": 654
"FireEye Inc.": 46
"First Data Corp.": 2
"First Solar Inc.": 92
"Fiserv Inc.": 151
"FleetCor Technologies Inc.": 1
"Fortinet Inc.": 35
"Gartner Inc.": 94
"Genpact Ltd.": 127
"Global Payments Inc.": 159
"GoDaddy Inc.": 31
IAC: 256
"IPG Photonics Corp.": 68
"Intel Corp.": 211
"International Business Machines Corp.": 341
"Juniper Networks Inc.": 74
"Leidos Holdings Inc.": 93
"LogMeIn Inc.": 92
"Manhattan Associates Inc.": 39
"Marvell Technology Group Ltd.": 44
"Mastercard Inc.": 155
"Match Group Inc.": 47
"Motorola Solutions Inc.": 148
"NCR Corp.": 213
"NVIDIA Corp.": 88
"National Instruments Corp.": 163
"ON Semiconductor Corp.": 972
"Pandora Media Inc.": 75
"PayPal Holdings Inc.": 274
"SS&C Technologies Holdings Inc.": 120
"Sabre Corp.": 100
"Salesforce.com Inc.": 30
"ServiceNow Inc.": 250
"Splunk Inc.": 36
"Square Inc.": 0
"Tableau Software Inc.": 18
"Teradata Corp.": 137
"Teradyne Inc.": 76
"Texas Instruments Inc.": 210
"The Ultimate Software Group Inc.": 344
"The Western Union Co.": 292
"Total System Services Inc.": 114
"Trimble Inc.": 128
"Twitter Inc.": 0
"Tyler Technologies Inc.": 45
"Universal Display Corp.": 42
"VeriSign Inc.": 52
"WEX Inc.": 173
"Workday Inc.": 51
"Worldpay Inc.": 131
"Xerox Corp.": 111
"Zebra Technologies Corp.": 110
"Zillow Group Inc.": 65
"Zynga Inc.": 12
```

Comment: Could you add the link to the Bloomberg site? Any chance that page has the other fields as well?

Comment: @ChristopherKlaus, I've added the link, https://www.bloomberg.com/graphics/ceo-pay-ratio/

Comment: A wonderful find! It looks like this link sources S&P 500 and Russell 1000 members. Not the full set of companies, but certainly a good chunk of them. If nobody finds more in the next couple days, then I’ll mark this as the answer. Thank you!